# Encoding a url with many characters

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook, encode

I want to encode a name so as to pass it to a url. My serie of names is in a dataframe, i want to pull that serie from the dataframe then encoded and then put it again in the dataframe, all the characters that i want to change are

```
':' : '%%3A'
'/' : '%%2F'
'(' : '%%28'
')' : '%%29'
';' : '%%3B'
'!' : '%%21'
'@' : '%%40'
'+' : '%%2B'
'$' : '%%24'
',' : '%%2C'
'*' : '%%2A'
'?' : '%%3F'
'#' : '%%23'
''  : '%%5B'
'%%': '%%25'
':' : '%%3A'
'/' : '%%2F'
' ' : '%%20')
```

the dataframe looks like this (there are more rows but i just an example)

```
 df
 id      name
 1    GH User
 2       Babo
 3      Kante
```

I try

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
   for i, j in dic.items():
      text = text.replace(i, j)
   return text


  reps = {' ':'%%20', ')':'%%29', '(':'%%28' , '/' : '%%2F' , ':' : '%%3A' , 
  ';': '%%3B' , '!' : '%%21' , '@' : '%%40' , '+' : '%%2B' , '$' : '%%24' , 
  ',' : '%%2C' , '*' : '%%2A' , '?' : '%%3F' , '#' : '%%23' , '' : '%%25' , 
  '%%' : '%%25' }

let = replace_all(df['name'], reps)
print(let)
```

But not working

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, `reps` is being defined inside the function. Also you want to replace an empty string with `%%25` which doesn't make any sense, and the replacement of `%%` must be done first or it'll run on the other replacements.

Comment: Do you know how i can correct it? :)

Comment: Knock it back by 2 spaces, you should be using 4 spaces per indent, currently you're switching between 2 and 3 so it's probably getting a bit more confusing :P